# Trigger that intercept sql command from the user

Tags: sql-server, logging, triggers, insert

How can I create a trigger that intercept which command the sql-user did in a target table (not the entire databank) when it fires an insert/update command.

Example:

When user do a update at the target table, the trigger intercepts it and insert a record in a `custom_log_table`. Same for an insert into target table...  the trigger also intercepts this command and saves into a `custom_log_table`.

The `custom_log_table` should have this fields: `timestamp`, `sql_user`, `ipAddress`, `sql_command`.

and the objective of this trigger is to detect who is messing with our records.

Answer (score 0):

SQL command can be saved using next:

```
declare @tmp table (EventType nvarchar(30), Parameters int, EventInfo nvarchar(4000))
insert into @tmp exec('DBCC INPUTBUFFER(@@SPID) WITH NO_INFOMSGS')
```

You can use `@tmp.EventInfo` afterwards. For user info, look at `SYSTEM_USER` variable or related functions.

Comment: something like this? CREATE TRIGGER LogComando
ON MULTA
AFTER UPDATE
AS
INSERT INTO LOG_COMANDO VALUES (GETDATE(),SYSTEM_USER,@tmp.EventInfo,exec('DBCC INPUTBUFFER(@@SPID) WITH NO_INFOMSGS'))

Comment: No, you have first to execute those two lines like I wrote. You can't insert stored procedure (like dbcc anything) results directly, you have to use temporary table.

Comment: and how do i get the comand from @tmp and save into log_comando table?

Comment: `insert into mytable (myfield, ...) values (@tmp.EventInfo, ...)`

Comment: @Arvo  If I use stored procedure to do Insert/Update, what DBCC INPUTBUFFER will return?

Comment: @Arvo Another question: If I launch my code where the first 4000 characters are just commented text, and my command starts below this comment? What will your code catch?

Comment: DBCC INPUTBUFFER catches top-level SQL statement (batch), for example call for procedure execution. You can try yourselves ;)